# EventListener for textarea value changed with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to detect when a textarea value has been changed with JavaScript?

I know that event listeners for `change` and `input` can detect changes that the user makes but I'm trying to detect when the value has been changed programmatically.

Is there any other way to do this?

Example:

```js
var area = document.getElementById('area');

area.addEventListener('input', function(){
  alert();
});

area.value = "hi"; // Shouldn't it fire the alert here?
```

```html
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
```

Comment: No, it won't fire because the user didn't input it...

Comment: initially you can check if text area value is blank or not and if not blank then you can trigger the change event,

Comment: Some code is modifying a textarea, and does so at an unknown time. I want to be able to run some of my own code when that textarea value is altered. If there isn't a way to do that, I'll have to rethink my strategy.

Comment: This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16013352/5788489

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect programmatic changes on input type text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013024/detect-programmatic-changes-on-input-type-text)

Comment: @KhorshedAlam Just what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me there!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea>Default value</textarea>

    <script>
            console.log($('textarea').val());
            $('textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
                console.log(this.value);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this works for when the user changes the text area, it does not call the function if the value is changed through JavaScript. https://jsfiddle.net/xtubwpuv/

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery, you can

```
$('#area').on('change keyup page', function(){
  alert();
});
```

Comment: While this works for when the user changes the text area, it does not call the function if the value is changed through JavaScript. https://jsfiddle.net/nojmkss6/